# Ограничивающая фигура динамического 3D объекта, библиотека Bullet

Tags: java, разработка-игр, libgdx, 3d

Столкнулся с проблемой создания ограничивающей фигуры для 3D объекта, моделька которого состоит из множества Mesh 
Для создания ограничивающей фигуры использую метод :
(изменил метод смомента последней публикации)

```
            /**Создает ограничивающую фигуру для динамичного объекта
     * @param model - 3D модель
     * @param optimize - флаг определяющий необходимость применения оптимизации (упрощения)
     * @param numMesh - более не используется (ограничивающая фигура строится по всем имеющимся Mesh)*/
    public static btConvexHullShape createConvexHullShape (final Model model, boolean optimize, int numMesh) {
        btConvexHullShape shape = null;
        int workBufferSize=0;
        int numVertex=0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= model.meshParts.size-1;i++) {
            final Mesh mesh = model.meshParts.get(i).mesh;
            numVertex += mesh.getNumVertices();
            workBufferSize += mesh.getVerticesBuffer().capacity();
        }
        FloatBuffer workBuffer = BufferUtils.newFloatBuffer(workBufferSize);
        for (int i = 0; i <= model.meshParts.size-1;i++) {
            Matrix4 transform = new Matrix4(model.nodes.get(0).localTransform);
//          transform.setToTranslation(model.meshParts.get(i).center.add(model.meshParts.get(i).halfExtents));
            final Mesh mesh = model.meshParts.get(i).mesh;

            FloatBuffer tempWorkBuffer = BufferUtils.newFloatBuffer(mesh.getVerticesBuffer().capacity());
            BufferUtils.copy(mesh.getVerticesBuffer(), tempWorkBuffer, mesh.getNumVertices() * mesh.getVertexSize() / 4);
            BufferUtils.transform(tempWorkBuffer, 3, mesh.getVertexSize(), mesh.getNumVertices(), transform);

            BufferUtils.copy(tempWorkBuffer, workBuffer, mesh.getNumVertices() * mesh.getVertexSize() / 4);
        }
        // Без оптимизации сверх точная ограничивающая фигура (но очень напряжно для CPU)
        // тут можно снять ! и будет видны точно все контуры ограничивающиз фигур    
        if (!optimize) {
            shape = new btConvexHullShape(workBuffer, numVertex, model.meshes.get(0).getVertexSize());
            return shape;
        }

        // First create a shape using all the vertices, then use the built in tool to reduce
        // the number of vertices to a manageable amount.
        btConvexShape convexShape = new btConvexHullShape(workBuffer, numVertex, model.meshes.get(0).getVertexSize());
        btShapeHull hull = new btShapeHull(convexShape);
        hull.buildHull(convexShape.getMargin());
        shape = new btConvexHullShape(hull);

        convexShape.dispose();
        hull.dispose();
        return shape;
    }
```

Таким образом мне удалось построить ограничивающую фигуру на основе всех имеющихся ограничивающих сеток(Mesh) 3D модели, однако осталась одна проблема.

- При создании ограничивающей фигуры для модели с 1й сеткой (Mesh) матрица трансформация получаемая

  Matrix4 transform = new Matrix4(model.nodes.get(0).localTransform);

и применяемая позже BufferUtils.transform отрабатывает нормально

- но как только модель более сложная все ограничивающие сетки сбиваются в кучу

ВОПРОС : как правильно получить их смещения и разнести их на нужные позиции

Полностью исходный код можно посмотреть [тут](https://github.com/leganas/LibGdx/tree/master/MyTest3DGame)

класс com.leganas.game.framework.graphics.engine3D.Phisics.java

Comment: Используя пример с GitHub изменил метод, не знаю как сюда его вставить использую редактирование поста

Comment: model.nodes это что? Вы же получаете матрицу у 0 нода и потом ее используете везде

Comment: сори, я так понял я запутался в терминологии, я перепутал Node(Узел) и Vertices (Вершина). Так вот Node это фигура к примеру квадрат или шар или любая другая сложная фигура (одна из составных частей всей модели). У каждого Node есть свой Mesh это собственно набор вершин из которых получается целостная 3D фигура, а уже по ней строится ограничивающая фигура для объекта твёрдого тела (она будет полностью окружать Mesh для этого Node) и соотвественно матрицу трансформации нужно брать у каждого отдельного Node и применять к каждому мешу.

Comment: Разобраться помог один видос https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1D5zmq9CIs, там также есть подсказка как правильно объединить несколько Mesh в один, я так понял нужно циклом пройтись по всем Node и их по всем их потомкам объединить все меши в один и по нему сделать ограничивающую фигуру. Далее будет уже вопроса как эта фигура будет отрабатывать при реализации анимации (движении руки и ног) будет ли она следовать за контурами модели при смещении костного скелета . Но это уже совсем другая история :)

Comment: Если модель разбита на несколько мешей, я не думаю, что это хорошая идея объединить меши для конвекса. Вы получите конвекс, который полностью охватывает вашу модель, при этом потеряете точность определения коллизий. Идем дальше, при анимации отдельные меши должны двигаться, при этом конвекс у вас на модель в дефолтовом состоянии, скажем так, если у модели к примеру поднять руку, то она вылезет из конвекса, опять таки проблема с коллизиями.

Comment: так и как мне тогда делать ограничивающую фигуру для данной модели ? что бы её все части были охвачены и при этом еще и с движением не было косяков ?

Comment: не совсем удачный пример, но думаю идею вы поймете. Здесь именно конвексы програмно делаются [ссылка](http://www.hypergridbusiness.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Convex-decomposition1.jpg)
как говорится - почувствуйте разницу. Но здесь модель разбивается на части из одного меша. Наверное для простоты нужно начать с конвекса на каждый меш. потом уже когда будете оптимизировать можно будет переделать